# Installation error in fedora 18

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,
I am trying to install gazebo for the first time in Fedora 18, After some work I manage to configure (cmake) without any error, some warnings, yes. When I run Make I get some errors at the very beginning of: Linking CXX executable gazebo, The erros are:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:180: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:751: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
util/libgazebo_util.so.1.8.1: undefined reference to `boost::thread::do_try_join_until_noexcept(timespec const&, bool&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [gazebo/gazebo-1.8.1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2.
```

I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Hugo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3009/installation-error-in-fedora-18/) by [Hugo Siles](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/369/hugo-siles/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-28**:
What operating system and boost version are you using?

**Comment by [Hugo Siles](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/369/hugo-siles/) on 2013-05-29**:
thank you very much for your answer, I am not quite sure about how to apply the patch, please give me some hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like a linking error. Can you try applying the following patch to the source code and rebuilding?

```
diff -r 684ea4ae5365 gazebo/util/CMakeLists.txt
--- a/gazebo/util/CMakeLists.txt    Tue May 28 17:36:39 2013 -0700
+++ b/gazebo/util/CMakeLists.txt    Tue May 28 22:46:11 2013 -0700
@@ -40,6 +40,7 @@
   gazebo_transport
   gazebo_math
   gazebo_msgs
+  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
 )
 
 gz_install_library(gazebo_util)
```

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hugo Siles](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/369/hugo-siles/) on 2013-05-29**:
the boost version I am using now is the boost_ 1_49_0 , I also tried the version boost_1_53_0, but I got more errors at different stages of the build up.

**Comment by [Hugo Siles](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/369/hugo-siles/) on 2013-05-29**:
thank you very much for your answer, I am not quite sure about how to apply the patch, please give me some hints.

**Comment by [Hugo Siles](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/369/hugo-siles/) on 2013-05-31**:
I made a patch file

**Comment by [Hugo Siles](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/369/hugo-siles/) on 2013-05-31**:
Ok here I am, I made a file with the above lines, put the file in a gazebo directory and run the patch file. I still have the errors during the make build.

**Comment by [Hugo Siles](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/369/hugo-siles/) on 2013-05-31**:
Ok here I am, I made a file with the above lines, put the file in a gazebo directory and run the patch file. I still have the errors during the make build.

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-06-01**:
the error seems to suggest that you are compiling against boost 1.53 headers but the linker is probably linking against 1.49 where these function definitions are not present. Do you have multiple boost versions installed?

**Comment by [Hugo Siles](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/369/hugo-siles/) on 2013-06-01**:
hummm, yes, first I instaled 1.53 but it gave errors in the cmake configuration, after wards I installed 1.49 and I managed to configure with no erros, but during the make build I got the above errors, I suppose that I have to uninstall one of the boost versions, how do I do that?